# auCDtect: Fatal error: glibc detected an invalid stdio handle

Tags: linux, shared-library, glibc, compatibility

I'm trying to use [auCDtect](http://tausoft.org/wiki/True_Audio_Checker_Overview) to check the authenticity of my audio files. I can run the linux binary successfully on my Synology NAS (DS918+) with the addition of libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3. I wanted to do this faster on my macbook pro laptop. I repeated the same step in Debian GNU Linux 9 (in Parallels Desktop), which resulted in this error:

```
Fatal error: glibc detected an invalid stdio handle
fish: 'aucdtect' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

gdb:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/local/bin/aucdtect
Fatal error: glibc detected an invalid stdio handle

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0xf7fd7c89 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0xf7fd7c89 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xf7d8fdf0 in raise () from /lib32/libc.so.6
#2  0xf7d912b7 in abort () from /lib32/libc.so.6
#3  0xf7dcb3af in ?? () from /lib32/libc.so.6
#4  0xf7dcb3ec in __libc_fatal () from /lib32/libc.so.6
#5  0xf7dcbd73 in ?? () from /lib32/libc.so.6
#6  0xf7da641b in vfprintf () from /lib32/libc.so.6
#7  0xf7dad7c8 in fprintf () from /lib32/libc.so.6
#8  0x080492d4 in ?? ()
#9  0xf7d7c286 in __libc_start_main () from /lib32/libc.so.6
#10 0x080489b1 in ?? ()
(gdb)
#0  0xf7fd7c89 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xf7d8fdf0 in raise () from /lib32/libc.so.6
#2  0xf7d912b7 in abort () from /lib32/libc.so.6
#3  0xf7dcb3af in ?? () from /lib32/libc.so.6
#4  0xf7dcb3ec in __libc_fatal () from /lib32/libc.so.6
#5  0xf7dcbd73 in ?? () from /lib32/libc.so.6
#6  0xf7da641b in vfprintf () from /lib32/libc.so.6
#7  0xf7dad7c8 in fprintf () from /lib32/libc.so.6
#8  0x080492d4 in ?? ()
#9  0xf7d7c286 in __libc_start_main () from /lib32/libc.so.6
#10 0x080489b1 in ?? ()
```

I guess this is probably because the program is too old (2004) and isn't compatible with the newer libraries. How can I figure out which library caused the problem (probably libc?), and which old version should I get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using auCDtect under wine for as long as I remember myself:

```bsh
wine ~/bin/auCDtect.exe -v -mS0 '*.wav'
```

You could also consider https://github.com/alexkay/spek which shows waveforms in a visual form. You can instantly see if the audio file has been processed by a bad encoder though good encoders e.g. Apple AAC even at 256Kbit/sec are often near impossible to detect this way but then auCDtect shows them as CDDA as well.

---

To see which shared libraries it uses you could run it via `ldd /path/to/binary`. It will not give you an understanding which versions of the libraries it needs.

Comment: I tried and it actually ended up 3 times faster than if I ran it in Parallels Debian VM (same file, same `-m0` settings). Thank you for your solution!

Comment: There's wine https://wiki.winehq.org/MacOS (and its paid version CrossOver https://www.codeweavers.com/crossover#mac ) for MacOS but as far as I know it only works if your CPU is x86 compatible (i.e. Intel or AMD). There's also PlayOnMac: https://www.playonmac.com/en/

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for my bad wording. I already have CrossOver. I'm talking about running linux program directly on macOS through a layer with wine-similar-concept.

Answer (score 0):

I used `ldd /usr/local/bin/aucdtect` to find the libraries `aucdtect` used (mainly libc and libm), copied them over from my NAS, put them in the same directory as `aucdtect`, and set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/local/bin`. Using this method, I was able to run `aucdtect` in the virtual machine. However, using `wine` on macOS is nearly 3x faster than using it in the virtual machine (sample size=1), so I ended up using `wine` instead.